# get result in callback function in jquery

Tags: jquery

How Can i get the result from this ajax , Can i pass it to hello function ?
the result is undefined in  `console.log(data);` in hello function

```
    $(function(){
     $.ajax({
                    url:'example.com',
                    type : 'POST' ,
                    async: false,
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    dataType: 'jsonp' , 
                    data : {
                        collectionName:'alltibyy',
                        facet: 'constellio',
                        fq: qt_value2,
                        wt: 'json',
                        hl: 'true',
                        q : key,
                        searchType: 'atLeastOneWord',
                        rows: '10',
                       'json.wrf': hello
                    },
                    success: function(json) {

                    },
                    error: function(e) {
                    console.log(e.message);
        }
    });

        });

 function hello(data)
    { 
      console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: Try to call it from the success callback. success: function(json) {
hello(json);
},

Answer (score 0):

soderslatt's answer will work.

The problem is that the ajax call has no knowledge of the hello function

Answer (score 0):

Move your hello function and callt from success and/or error callback.
jsfiddle= >http://jsfiddle.net/Ye9fa/

```
$(function() {

    function hello(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }

    var qt_value2, key;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'example.com',
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: {
            collectionName: 'alltibyy',
            facet: 'constellio',
            fq: qt_value2,
            wt: 'json',
            hl: 'true',
            q: key,
            searchType: 'atLeastOneWord',
            rows: '10'
        },
        success: function(json) {
            hello(json);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            hello(e);
        }
    });

});​
```